# Android: menu and action bar missing with android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-manifest

My Android app has android:minSdkVersion="12" and android:targetSdkVersion="15" in the manifest.
Until yesterday it appeared as having an action bar and a menu with some items on action bar itself and some in the menu as set programmatically.
After installing a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 system and eclipse, after some trouble now it compiles and installs on real device with Android 4.0.3 (Acer IconiaTab A100 tablet) but it has no action bar and no menu on the action bar or on the navigation bar.
Edit: it happens the same with minSdkVersion="15" too. It's weird.

Comment: which theme are you using as default for your application?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct SDK installed and using the needed support libraries for the Actionbar.

Comment: @ Android-Developer It's App-Theme name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light". @Martijn Van Mierloo Support Library was installed. I installed Support Repository too but nothing changes with minSdk 12 or 15.

Comment: I deleted the manifest entry about theme and menu was there again.